# Is there an MS-Graph API end-point to retrieve Microsoft Teams PSTN and SMS usage?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I noticed in our dashboard that Microsoft provides an SMS and PSTN usage report which captures each incoming and outgoing call and conference call (duration, callerID, etc...). I need this data to be queryable over the Graph API but after hours of combing though the docs I can't find any report which matches the schema of the report provided in the dashboard.

Is there any graph api endpoint or cascade of endpoints which I could collect this data from?

Schema of report below: Call ID,Conference ID,User Location,Display Name,Caller ID,Call Type,Number Type,Domestic/International,Destination Dialed,Destination Number,Start Time,End Time,Duration Seconds,Connection Fee,Charge,Currency,Capability

[image]

Comment: You can take a look into Graph API for a [Peer-to-Peer call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-getting-a-peer-to-peer-call). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT That doesn't seem to be useful as I do not have the call-Ids beforehand in order to perform the query and the result of the query does not include duration or date of the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no Graph API available to get PSTN & SMS report. Please raise a uservoice so we can take it for future release.

Comment: "raise a uservoice" ? I am unfamiliar with that terminology. What is this and where should it be done?

Comment: Found an existing issue on UserVoice that matched our intent closely. Added my vote and comments there https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/39011170-pstn-usage-report-export-view-via-powerbi-or-t

Answer (score 1):

There is a beta version of the report in Graph now - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls?view=graph-rest-beta